# pChart php graph generation

Tags: php, pchart

I want to know a way of inverting the y-axis using pChart. I want the y-axis to start at 0 and 1,2,3,4 etc down, rather than up if that makes sense. In the case of search engine rankings a lower number is better and I want the graph to reflect that by inverting the y-axis. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Search engines don't care if your y-axis is upside down, especially on an a bitmap image file. You're just making your code less maintainable. Just use pChart they way it's intended.

Comment: I had a pretty good idea of what I was trying to achieve and all I wanted to know was pChart capable of doing it, now I know I won't pursue it. I found your answer unfriendly but not unhelpful.

Comment: @olw: I'm sorry the tone of my answer upset you. I'll be more courteous in the future.

Comment: He's not trying to make a chart SEO-friendly. The search engine comment was in reference to the data he's plotting.

Answer (score 0):

My only suggestion is to make the rankings as negative numbers. It may not be a perfect representation, but it will invert the axis values, and should still be readable.